# java generate ID from user input

Tags: java, arrays, list

Very new to the Java world.

How do I assign user input into an ID array? (e.g. the first id is 1,then 2, 3 so on)

LinkedList for objects? e.g. `cat`

Ask for user to input type of `cat` and assign it to a unique ID.

How to do search for ID after created??

```
LinkedList<Cat> cats = new LinkedList<Cat>();
```

Comment: too much broad or complex please modify it properly

Answer (score 2):

When the need to have unique IDs, the easiest is to use a GUID (Global Unique Identifier). A few example for unique GUIDs:

```
3c991b3e-1396-4182-9663-a24b3bc7f1b1
effa71c0-d657-4161-9bd9-aff7ccb545b3
dfb20317-3d70-4ec9-8d9a-d3cdc9895bdf
4f78c930-5ba6-4e45-a659-ac7e5eab6177
```

These are mathematically proven to be unique within a system for years. Read more [about GUIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) on wikipedia and about [duplications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates): 
"only after generating 1 billion UUIDs every second for the next 100 years, the probability of creating just one duplicate would be about 50%."

to do this, use the java internal UUID class. As for the cat example, do:

```
public Cat(/*constructor arguments here*/) {
  this.id = UUID.randomUUID();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do one of two things:

1. Use ArrayList and have the indices be your unique ID.
2. Add a field to Cat of a unique ID and have a static member of Cat store the last given ID. That way, each element will receive a unique ID. You can then search elements by their IDs.

Example code for (2):

```
public class Cat {

     private static int counter = 0;

     private final int id;
     //.. other private fields

     public Cat(/*constructor arguments here*/) {
         this.id = counter++;
         //other constructor code
     }

     //Cat class implementation

}
```

Comment: You should make `id` final, so no one will ever have the idea to change it later.

Comment: You're completely right. I've edited my answer accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would not suggest using a LinkedList for this. To have an unique ID that is linked to your object, you could use a HashMap. It is basically a key-value map where no duplicated key's are allowed.

Example:

```
Map<Integer, Cat> cats = new HashMap<Integer, Cat>();
cats.put(1, cat01);
cats.put(2, cat02);
Cat cat01 = cats.get(1);
```